# How to convert ASP.NET webhost builder code to .NET 6 / avoid ASP0009 warning/error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

How can I create a WebApplicationBuilder instance without using `Configure()` which is deprecated in .NET6/7?

Compiler says: `[ASP0009] Configure cannot be used with WebApplicationBuilder.WebHost`

My current code snippet:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

builder.WebHost.Configure(app =>
    {
        app
            .UseRouting()
            .UseAuthentication()
            .UseEndpoints(_ => _.MapDefaultControllerRoute()
            );
    }
);
return builder;
```

I need a "builder" instance because after this code more configuration gets added before `.Build()` can be called.

I could not find a replacement especially for `.UseEndPoints(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

For minimal APIs, you need to configure middlewares and routes on the `WebApplication` itself, such as:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseEndpoints(_ => _.MapDefaultControllerRoute());

app.Run();
```

Comment: `app.UseEndpoints(_ => _.MapDefaultControllerRoute());` can be changed to `app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();` - see my answer.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for a way to configure this before `.Build()` because that is called in a different assembly.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to move everything to the "root":

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
```

Or with chaining:

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRouting()
   .UseAuthentication(); // can chain this calls because they use IApplicationBuilder

app.MapDefaultControllerRoute(); // no chaining here, requires IEndpointRouteBuilder
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for a way to configure this before `.Build()` because that is called in a different assembly.

Comment: @stb you need to give more context. Why you can't call it after build in another assembly?

Comment: @stb also not that generic hosting model (the one with startups) still supported and there is no need to migrate to the minimal one.

Comment: For consistency and DRY reasons I create a full configured *Builder in a separate library (auth, custom filter...) which is used in multiple projects. Most projects are just simple APIs and therefore need only a one-liner to include this but some need more configuration before .Build(). I don't use (old) ASP.NET templates (Startup.cs).

I want to migrate to the new model because it has the same goal as my builder code (will improve my code) and because some methods like `.UseSerilog()` already are marked deprecated.

Comment: @stb you can move "afterbuild" setup to those libreries, what's the problem?

Comment: Currently I have an initial setup (builder) in a central lib (DRY) and customization in multiple projects. With "afterbuild" I have to bite either the bullet of loosing DRY for afterbuild or the bullet of having ping pong flow (central builder, builder customization, build, central afterbuild, afterbuild customization) making it hard to know which setting overrides which other. Nevertheless this might be the smaller bullet.